# Android Programming TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: In the red box in the image you see my current textviews. Im trying to copy/paste them multiple times and place them below my current textviews.]I have 3 `TextViews` called with the id's `aaa`, `headertext` and `headertext2`. The `TextView` called `aaa` fills the width and the `headertext` and `headertext2` fills 50% of the width each.

I would like to duplicate these 3 `TextViews` so they appear below my current `TextViews`, so the result is I have 6 `ListViews`. I think I'm mixing up the `LinearLayout` and the `RelativeLayout`, and therefore I can't get it to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="KALENDER"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/button2" />

      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Image1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none">   

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aaa"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFÈEN´S åbningstider"
                    android:textColor="#0AABA4"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp" 
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/test"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2.0">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/headerText"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mandag - Onsdag\nTorsdag - Lørdag\nSøndag"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/headerText2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="kl. 10.00 - 22.00\nkl. 10.00 - 00.00\nkl. 10.00 - 16.00"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please show image what is actually trying to do ?

Comment: I have done so now. Thank you.

Comment: @Chrfugl is that a dynamic list?

Comment: No static. Text from strings.

Answer (score 2):

before these tags at end:

```
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

insert the copy of the 2nd RelativeLayout(from beginning) `<RelativeLayout>.textviews1,2,3..</RelativeLayout>`

This is the way your code is working:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:text="KALENDER"
.../>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Image1"
.../>
<ScrollView
...>
<LinearLayout
...>

LAYOUT_FOR_THREE_TEXT_BOXES_HERE

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[finalCode](http://pastebin.com/RxFr6E1V)

Comment: @Chrfugl please post a screenshot of how you want your final view to look like(using something like paint)

Comment: A image should be available

Comment: the link to finalCode was displaying 2X(3 textViews) when i checked it on my computer

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uHxPvbrR try this code and dont forget to change the ids of text views.

Comment: P.S. a conceptual understanding of how these nested views are working will help you understand it clearly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55490/discussion-between-pendudev-and-chrfugl).